# Google Script get files names into spreadsheet issues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a code App Script that lists all the Folder Names and Files names into a Spreadsheet which works good until I rename one of the folders or file. Then the next time I run the script it will not include the renamed Folder/File into the Spreadsheet. Is there something I have done wrong in the script? 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Link to spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T3eKmyXKhLCbcoMdZRzMQ1__-dL3bTlH0wMKaWVFJ1Y/edit?usp=sharing

Link to Google Script: https://script.google.com/d/1LVTe29Y3jDbElt8LM4ciZ8Kj0gPzmFAxawZaYmRaFvkkfrewtJ5fxO0B/edit?usp=sharing

Link to Folder: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VPQC9Cp4QT0r_ILmq9c0nOsSSduqh6jg?usp=sharing

```
function listFolders(folder) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T3eKmyXKhLCbcoMdZRzMQ1__-dL3bTlH0wMKaWVFJ1Y/edit#gid=0');
  var first = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  first.clear("A2:D405");

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T3eKmyXKhLCbcoMdZRzMQ1__-dL3bTlH0wMKaWVFJ1Y/edit#gid=0');
  sheet.appendRow(["File Name", "URL", "Folder Name"]);

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1VPQC9Cp4QT0r_ILmq9c0nOsSSduqh6jg');
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();

  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    //Logger.log(folder);
    var name = subfolders.next();
    while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
      //Logger.log(folder);
      var name = subfolders.next();
      var files = name.getFilesByType('application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet');
      var cnt = 0;
      var file;

      while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        cnt++;
        Logger.log(file);
        Logger.log(cnt);

        data = [
          file.getName(),
          file.getUrl(),
          name, //folder name
        ];
        sheet.appendRow(data);
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it will not include'? are you saying the renamed folder would be removed from the spreadsheet?

Comment: You've got some interesting `while`-loop logic, which is what I expect is causing your missing files and folders.

Comment: Yes, that is right. The renamed folder would be removed from the spreadsheet.
And how should I fix the `while`-loop logic problem?

Thanks!